# Getting data from HDFS using Sparkstreaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to read data from HDFS using spark streaming.
Below is my code.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
import org.apache.hadoop.io.{LongWritable, Text}
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat

val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

val directory ="hdfs://pc-XXXX:9000/hdfs/watchdirectory/"
val lines=ssc.fileStream[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat](directory, (t:Path) => true, true).map(_._2.toString)
lines.count()
lines.print()
ssc.start
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The code runs but it does not read any data from HDFS. 
After every 10 seconds I get a blank line.

I have gone through the document for fileStream and I know that I have move the file to the watch directory. 
But it doesn't work for me. 
I have also tried with textFileStream but no luck.

I am using spark 2.0.0 built with Scala 2.11.8

Any suggestions please.

Comment: how did you try with textFileStream , post your code please

Comment: There was no major difference but here is the line of code which I changed . `val lines = ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://pc-XXXX:9000/hdfs/watchdirectory/")`

Comment: Use textFileStream and move the file after running the spark program ,it will not pick if the file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(10))

val lines= ssc.textFileStream("hdfs://pc-XXXX:9000/hdfs/watchdirectory/").map(_._2.toString)
lines.count()
lines.print()
ssc.start
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Once you execute this , move the files to

```
/hdfs/watchdirectory/
```

Comment: I have already that before posting the question but it does not work for me

Comment: how are you running ? which mode ? local , YARN ,Meson,Stand alone ?

Comment: Tried using local and standalone